# MongoTemplate returning NullPoint exception on Executing second Time

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I want to get a data from mongo and I have created a bean for a mongo using the spring data, but the problem is It runs and is giving the data successfully only at the first time but when I call the same template for the second time I am getting the **NullPointException**

Here is my code::

```
try{
            mongoTemplate = (MongoTemplate) ApplicationContextProvider.getBean("mongoTemplate");
            UsageMapping usageMapping = mongoTemplate.findById(salesOrg, UsageMapping.class);
            usagemapAsObject = usageMapping.getUsages();
            String usageMappingJSON = JsonUtil.getJsonFromObject(usagemapAsObject); //mapper.writeValueAsString(usagemapAsObject);
            if(InsightUtil.isEmpty(usageMappingJSON)){
                LOGGER.warn("No value found for "
                        + EnvironmentConstants.USAGE_SETUP_MAPPING);
                return new HashMap();
            }
            usageMap = JsonUtil.getObjectFromJson(usageMappingJSON, Map.class);

        }catch (Exception e){
            LOGGER.warn("Exception in Mongo:: "+ EnvironmentConstants.USAGE_SETUP_MAPPING);
        }
```

Here is my ApplicationContextProvider Class::

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
            throws BeansException {
        appContext = context;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String name) {
        return  appContext.getBean(name);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you try this ?
`@Autowired
 private ApplicationContext context;` and then `mongoTemplate = (MongoTemplate) context.getBean("mongoTemplate");`

Comment: Can you post `ApplicationContextProvider` class?

Comment: I have updated the question you can see now

Comment: Replace `mongoTemplate = (MongoTemplate) ApplicationContextProvider.getBean("mongoTemplate");` with           `mongoTemplate = (MongoTemplate) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("mongoTemplate");`. You need to add a getter to `ApplicationContextProvider` class to return `ApplicationContext` instance. `public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }` This should work fine

Comment: Also, you don't need `public static Object getBean(String name) {
        return  appContext.getBean(name);
    }` method in your class